# Tomcat started, but still Error 404

Tags: tomcat

I'm a bit tired about searching stuff with tomcat 404 error.
I'm using Eclipse NEON and everything worked fine, but then just Eclipse lagged, I had to restart it. I hitted "tomcat start" again and..

> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Tomcat 8.5

I don't want to paste whole project here, because everything worked before this lag. I downloaded again my SVN project, listen 8080 port.. I just don't have more ideas.

Comment: Are there any errors in the catalina, local access or any other tomcat log?  I am not sure what "Eclipse lagged" means, but tomcat is very deterministic, if it worked, it will keep working unless you change something.  Have you tried restarting your computer, eclipse has a tendency to leave a running and detached tomcat process which is still listening to the port and preventing new processes from starting (since the port is in use).

Comment: Sorry that I'm replying now, but finally I've found the problem. When my eclipse lagged (I mean - I had to close eclipse with manager) my file from Tomcat/catalina/localhost dissapeared - don't know how :P
When I copied again my file there, everything works.